# What percentage of cards have taunt?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone, what percentage of cards have taunt?

This is relevant to strategies where you have the choice to "destroy a minion and replace it with one better" situations and you need a taunt.

Answer (score 5):

There are total of 2 758 cards in the game as of  December 2018, the release date of the last expansion(Rastakhan's Rumble). From these, 148 collectible cards have taunt and 42 collectible (summoned, found or otherwise not normally acquired) cards having taunt, for total of 190 cards with taunt.

In addition, there are 44 cards that can give creatures a taunt effect, summon a taunt minion or discover a creatures with taunt specifically.

As a result, percentage of *creatures* with taunt is 190/2758= 0.06889...or roughly 7%. If you include the taunt giving cards, number bumbs to about 8.5%.

Sources:

1. https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Card
2. https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Taunt/Wild_format

Comment: Great answer. I'll probably do it myself at some point but do you have the stats for Standard minions?

Comment: @Studoku There are 64 minions with taunt out of 1049 standard cards. There are many more minions/spells that can gain, give, spawn or transform into taunts (see [here](https://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/cards/?st&manaCost&format=standard&rarity&type&class&set&mechanic=126&race&orderby=ASC-name&view=gallery) for any cards mentioning "Taunt"). But there are 64 minions who actually have "true" Taunt on their card (by default) and would have Taunt if they were to spawn from a deathrattle for example. So that works out at 6.1% of standard cards are "true" Taunt minions.

Comment: Ok, so if somebody uses the Witchy Lackey to try to put up a taunt it is a real hail mary then, because they only have a 7% chance of succeeding, then, is that right?

Comment: @TylerDurden If this is going where I think it is, swearing when your opponent's taunt showed up was entirely justified.